# Castalia and omnetpp simulation of WVSN

Tags: simulator, omnet++

OMNETPP simulation of WVSN

I am facing error,
 Error: Error loading NED sources from `.': NED error in file`ThroughputTest.ned': declared package `node.application.throughputTest' does not match expected package`Castalia-files.input.src.node.application.throughputTest'.

Comment: You really need to give more information on what you are trying to do. I assume you have changed something from the original distribution of Castalia. The error message is quite descriptive. Is there something you do not understand about it?